# Comparing a list of lists to a list in python

Tags: python, jython, jes

I'm trying to to compare a list of lists to a simple list in JES 
This is a sample of the data that im trying to compare

```
list1 = [(1, 'abc'), (5, 'no'), (5, 'not'), (10, 'which')]
 list2 = ['not', 'which', 'abc']
```

Basically what i'm doing is comparing a set of words and their frequencies (list1) with a list of distinct words (list2), if list 2 matches list 1 make a new list that contains the same word and the frequency from list1
This is an example of the list 3 output below

```
list3 = [(5, 'not'), (10, 'which'), (1, 'abc')]
```

This is using JES which is missing some of the full functionality of python, so id assume i can only answer this with a for loop or such

this is what I've tried so far, also a few other combinations

```
list3 = []
    for x in keywords:
     for y in frequencyList:
        if x == y[1]:
            list3.append(y)
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: list2 actually containds variable names, to changes them to words please add quotes ;)

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python I would do:

```
list3 = [x for x in list1 if x[1] in list2]
```

Not sure about JES though

Comment: is that referred to as list comprehension? 

I will give it a go

Comment: Indeed, it is. Please, come back to me if any trouble.

Comment: It worked, i appreciate the help.
Honestly didn't think it would be that simple 

i will accept the answer once it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter with a lambda function making things more pythonic!

```
>>> list1 = [(1, 'abc'), (5, 'no'), (5, 'not'), (10, 'which')]
>>> list2 = ['not', 'which', 'abc']
>>> filter(lambda x:x[1] in list2,list1)
[(1, 'abc'), (5, 'not'), (10, 'which')]
```